# C# thread method return a value?

Tags: c#, multithreading, return, void

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access return value from Thread.Start()'s delegate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942255/access-return-value-from-thread-starts-delegate-function)

```
public string sayHello(string name)
{
    return "Hello ,"+ name;
}
```

How can i use this method in Thread?

That ThreadStart method just accept void methods.

I'm waiting your helps.
Thank you.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Not only does `ThreadStart` expect void methods, it also expect them not to take any arguments! You can wrap it in a lambda, an anonymous delegate, or a named static function.

Here is one way of doing it:

```
string res = null;
Thread newThread = new Thread(() => {res = sayHello("world!");});
newThread.Start();
newThread.Join(1000);
Console.Writeline(res);
```

Here is another syntax:

```
Thread newThread = new Thread(delegate() {sayHello("world!");});
newThread.Start();
```

The third syntax (with a named function) is the most boring:

```
// Define a "wrapper" function
static void WrapSayHello() {
    sayHello("world!);
}

// Call it from some other place
Thread newThread = new Thread(WrapSayHello);
newThread.Start();
```

Comment: It's have been helpful for me. Thank you.

Comment: I couldn't get return value. How can use return value?

Comment: [ParameterizedThreadStart Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight this did not work for me, can you please help ?

Answer (score 3):

You should be using a [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx) for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use any method of threading, try `BackgroundWorker`:

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
    bw.RunWorkerAsync("MyName");
}

void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Text = (string)e.Result;
}

void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    string name = (string)e.Argument;
    e.Result = "Hello ," + name;
}
```